# completely remove wine

Tags: uninstall

I tried to remove wine from the terminal using :

`apt-get remove wine`

but wine still exists. How can I remove it completely?

```
harsh@harsh-BOOK:~$ sudo get-apt purge Q4Wine
[sudo] password for harsh: 
sudo: get-apt: command not found
harsh@harsh-BOOK:~$ sudo get-apt purge wine
sudo: get-apt: command not found
harsh@harsh-BOOK:~$ sudo rm wine
rm: cannot remove ‘wine’: No such file or directory
harsh@harsh-BOOK:~$ sudo rm q4wine
rm: cannot remove ‘q4wine’: No such file or directory
harsh@harsh-BOOK:~$ sudo rm winetricks
rm: cannot remove ‘winetricks’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Use `sudo apt-get purge wine`

Comment: You are getting errors because the command `get-apt` does not exist, the correct command is `apt-get`.

Comment: You're running the wrong command: it's `apt-get`, not `get-apt`.

Answer (score 8):

You used `get-apt` instead of `apt-get`.

`rm` is for removing files, not packages.

Comment: +1 for mentioning about `rm`

Comment: i used all these commands in correct way. wine still exist. when i run wine its not open but those applications install by  wine are open.  give me another way to remove this entirely

Answer (score 5):

The command is:

```
sudo apt-get purge wine
```

You had written `get-apt` by mistake, as highlighted by the error code.

Comment: i did it in correct way also, but still wine exist.  another way to remove it entirely?

Answer (score 4):

The Command to remove wine package is:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge wine
```

But the `~./wine` directory is still kept, and it contains all your installed wine applications and settings. Remove this folder and all its contents with this command:

```
rm -rf ~/.wine
```